# Pausing a Thead in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to pause my game, but, I only know about Thread.sleep, and, I have no idea how to make it actually pause untill you resume with that method. How will I pause my game untill I want to resume it?

Comment: See [this example here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/PauseThread.html)

Comment: Is your game driven by an event loop or by user events / timers?

Comment: I think yield just halts the current thread and waits for others to finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make it to wait on condition:

```
synchronized(lock) {
 while(paused) {
   lock.wait();
 }
}
```

Modern way to do the same thing is to use `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition` [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)

Comment: This gave me an idea. Let me put this to the test.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `wait` and `notify` to lock on an object before each iteration.  If an object has issued a `wait` on an object the game is paused until the user selects the resume option and the object is released using a `notify` call.

Check out this link for a tutorial .. http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=306

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Lock

```
private final Lock pauser = new ReentrantLock();
```

In the thread you want to pause.

```
pauser.lock();
pauser.unlock();
```

To stop anything trying to use the pauser

```
pauser.lock();
```

To free the pauser

```
pauser.unlock();
```